# Redshift DISTSTYLE KEY. Deciding whats the best column to define as KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Well I recently got into this area of Redshift, trying to optimize disk usage and performance of my database, and having read lots of information on AWS about the topic, I still have some doubts.
First of all, to my database structure. Per schema, I have 3 master tables, with 3 different IDs, these are now DISTSTLYE ALL tables, being small in size.

Each master table has different amounts of IDs,

the date table --> largest one (#1 most joined)

the store table --> medium one (#3 most joined)

the item table --> smallest one (#2 most joined)

Then I have my core table, which has needed combinations of these IDs to display additional information about them. Anyway, this table should be a DISTSTYLE KEY type, based on my knowledge. Well, which of the 3 IDs should I select to be my DIST KEY?

Whats the criteria for this decision? I understand that for joins I need to look at the Sort Key, well that has been understood and defined to the ID_date, because its the most joined table. So now, what about the distribution per node of this table?

I'm sorry if I'm rambling, I dont want to leave any information out. If I have, feel free to ask! Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: As a general rule, I look to distribute my largest table using the highest-cardinality foreign key.

Comment: If you want more information, please edit your question to list all of your tables, with the number of rows in each, and the foreign keys. For example: if your database contains eCommerce orders, you might have a `LINE_ITEMS` table with a foreign key `ORDER_ID` that ties it to the `ORDERS` table. Show the number of rows in each table that will be involved in the joins.

Answer (score 6):

You'll find the best advice on [Amazon Redshift best practices for designing tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-tables-best-practices.html). It goes into quite a bit of detail.

However, my rule of thumb is:

- The `DISTKEY` should be the column most used in JOINs between tables
- The `SORTKEY` should be the column most used in WHERE statements
- Use `DISTSTYLE ALL` for small lookup tables